# OPENROWSET and SINGLE BLOB in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using sqlserver 2005 here i wrote simple bulk image upload query using openrowset with single blob function. But my query is not executing. showing T-Sql is not support Sql server 2005 and below version.

Here i using query like,

```
create table Student_Images(Image_Id int identity,Images image Primary key(Image_Id))

INSERT INTO Student_Images(Images) 
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(BULK N'E:\COE\Images\UHSA1406.jpg',SINGLE_BLOB) as Images
```

Can u suggest the reference link. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Try declaring Images column datatype as varbinary(max) instead of image datatype.

Comment: Pleas be aware that `image` as a data type will be removed in future versions. Instead, use `varbinary`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.90).aspx. Can you post the exact error message you get? The statement you listed in itself should be correct for SQL Server 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @knkarthik24  I am getting error after executing the code like,         Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger. The Transact-SQL debugger does not support SQL Server 2005 or earlier versions of SQL Server.(SQL Editor)

Comment: Google gave me this answer for your error.So you too try https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8b814886-f27b-48b4-be0b-4adf2b1affdd/transactsql-debugger-not-working-in-sql-server-2008-debugger-does-not-support-sql-server-2005?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: Then, Is there any way to write a Bulk image load query in sqlserver2005?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the actual error message you posted in the comment, it seems that you are trying to run your query from SQL Server Management Studio with a higher version than your server is running. This could be because thge machine you're attempting to run the query from has a later installation.

To resolve the error, install the 2005 SQL Server Management Studio, or run the query directly on the server using the SQL Server 2005 Management Studio.